# Rake db:migrate SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I did the installfest project setup:

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app
and got this error when doing `rake db:migrate`.

I have tried re-installing rails and ruby, but that didn't work.

Using:

- Ruby 2.2.1
- Rails 4.2.1
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu is set up with vagrant (VM) on a windows 8.1 host

  `vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/odin/test_app$ rake db:migrate --trace`

> ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
>       ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>       ** Execute environment
>       ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>       ** Execute db:load_config
>       ** Execute db:migrate
>       rake aborted!
>       ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error:           SELECT name
>                 FROM sqlite_master
>                 WHERE (type = 'table' OR type = 'view') AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
>        AND name = "schema_migrations"
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   new'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `prepare'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in`block in exec_query'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in`exec_query'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:374:in `tables'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:380:in`table_exists?'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:21:in
>   `table_exists?'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:25:in`
>   create_table'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:805:in
>   `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:922:in`
>   initialize'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in
>   `new'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in`
>   up'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in
>   `migrate'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in`
>   migrate'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in`
>   call'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `block in execute'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in`
>   each'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `execute'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in
>   `invoke'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in`
>   invoke_task'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   each'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   block in run'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
>       SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   initialize'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `new'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   prepare'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in `block in exec_query'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in`block in log'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
>   `instrument'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in`log'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in `exec_query'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:374:in`tables'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:380:in `table_exists?'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:21:in`
>   table_exists?'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:25:in
>   `create_table'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:805:in`
>   initialize_schema_migrations_table'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:922:in
>   `initialize'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in`
>   new'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in
>   `up'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in`
>   migrate'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in
>   `migrate'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `call'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in`
>   block in execute'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `each'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in`
>   execute'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in`
>   invoke'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in
>   `invoke_task'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `each'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   block in top_level'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in
>   `run_with_threads'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in`
>   top_level'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in
>   `block in run'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in
>   `run'
>       /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in`'
>       Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem changing the NFS shared folders mount options!

```
mount_options:['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1']
```

Now rake db:migrate runs fine!